# Can some help explain the logic that is happening with this recursion output?

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following class

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop = 0

    def bar(self):
        self.stop += 1
        print(self.stop)

        if self.stop < 5:
            print('before first bar')
            self.bar()

            print('before second bar')
            self.bar()

            return None
```

If I run the following

```
foo = Foo()

foo.bar()

print(f"the value of foo.stop is {foo.stop}")
```

then I get the following output

```
1
before first bar
2
before first bar
3
before first bar
4
before first bar
5
before second bar
6
before second bar
7
before second bar
8
before second bar
9

the value of foo.stop is 9
```

I am unsure whats going on here and how is the recursion taking place? It seems like the first call of `bar` in the if-statement is being called until `foo.stop = 5`, but then how is the second call of `bar` in the if-statement being called 4 additional times?

Comment: Visualise it at http://pythontutor.com…

Comment: To get to `self.stop=5`, you obviously have to be four levels deep in recursion.  And then you still need to process the _second_ call to `self.bar()` in each of those four levels, which adds another 4 to `self.stop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion level 1: `foo.bar()` is called, it increments `self.stop` to 1, then prints it.  The condition `self.stop < 5` is true, so it goes into the `if` block. This prints `before the first bar` and calls the function again.

Recursion level 2: `self.stop` is incremented to 2 and printed. The condition is again true, so it prints `before the first bar` and calls the function again.

Recursion level 3: `self.stop` is incremented to 3 and printed. The condition is again true, so it prints `before the first bar` and calls the function again.

Recursion level 4: `self.stop` is incremented to 4 and printed. The condition is again true, so it prints `before the first bar` and calls the function again.

Recursion level 5: `self.stop` is incremented to 5 and printed. Now the condition is false, so it skips the `if` block. The function returns to recursion level 4.

Recursion level 4: it prints `before the second bar`, and calls the function again.

Recursion level 5: `self.stop` is incremented to 6 and printed. The condition is again false, so it returns to level 4.

Recursion level 4: it executes `return None` and returns to level 3.

Recursion level 3: prints `before the second bar` and calls the function again.

Recursion level 4: `self.stop` is incremented to 7 and printed. The condition is again false, so it returns to level 3.

Recursion level 3: it executes `return None` and returns to level 2.

Recursion level 2: prints `before the second bar` and calls the function again.

Recursion level 3: `self.stop` is incremented to 8 and printed. The condition is again false, so it returns to level 2.

Recursion level 2: it executes `return None` and returns to level 1.

Recursion level 1: prints `before the second bar` and calls the function again.

Recursion level 2: `self.stop` is incremented to 9 and printed. The condition is again false, so it returns to level 1.

Recursion level 1: it executes `return None` and returns to the original caller.

So the reason it keeps incrementing the number is because it increments and prints it *before* it checks whether it's reached the limit. And it performs 2 recursive calls before returning, so each recursion is able to increment twice.

Answer (score 0):

- You start the function with `stop` being zero.
- Every call increments the one state regardless
- An `if` if state is less than 5. 1,2,3, and 4 will all be less
- Once in the `if` it will recurse twice so even `4` will call the recursion twice bumping state to `6` before it returns to the original `3` version that will increment it to `7` and all down to the initial recursive call where the state before the call was 1 ending in the state being 9